# Initialize placeholder if value is not provided

Tags: tensorflow

Is there an elegant way to specify a default value for a placeholder?

If you specify a value in the `run(feed_dict=...)` then uses that value otherwise it defaults to a given value that you specify at build time.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just found it myself:

```
tf.placeholder_with_default(input, shape, name=None)
```